# Check is IEnumerable<T> has 5 or more matches

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, count

I have an IEnumerable that where T is a complex object. I need to check and see if there are 5 or more items in the list that match a lambda expression. Currently I am using something like this:

```
if(myList.Count(c=> c.PropertyX == desiredX && c.Y != undesiredY) >= 5)...
```

However, I myList grows to containing 10K+ objects this becomes a huge bottle neck and more than likely it will have found a match in the first 100 items (but I can't make that assumption).

How can I do this as efficiently as possible.

Comment: Thanks all - Never used skip in all my years of programming... Not I have a reason!

Comment: Do you actually then want to get these five and do something with them or will you be processing everything once there are five matches? I note that in some answers it checks they exist but effectively throws them away which means if you need them you might then be doing the predicate all over again which may not be efficient if you are potentially checking a lot of objects...

Comment: I'm grabbing a list of all object that I currently want to work with (500 - 10K objects). I then need to check that list to make sure there are at least 5 of each item type in that list. If not, I let the user know that this collection does not have the minimum number of items of type X.  Then I go back to working with the larger collection.

Comment: Ah, cool. Then the skip/any checks are fine performance-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Where` to filter, then `Skip` the first 4 matches and use `Any` which will stop iterating once it hits the 5th match.  The case where there are less than 5 matches will still have to iterate the entire list though.

```
if(myList.Where(c=> c.PropertyX == desiredX && c.Y != undesiredY).Skip(4).Any())
```

Comment: Works great. Cut my CPU time on the method using this from 5% down to 1.5%. Still need to find a way to make it more efficient, but this will work for now.

Comment: If you want to make it more efficient you might want to not use linq. You say in comments above you are checking there are at least five of each item type which suggests you are doing this multiple times which means iterating over those start objects repeatedly. You might be better off just foreaching the list and keeping a tally of each item you are interested in as you go, that way you would do all your checks in one iteration whereas multiple uses of this where/skip/any code will iterate the list for each one (up until the point the condition is satisfied).

Comment: @Chris That assumes the contents of the list do not change and you can midigate that by just assigning the result of the `Any` call to a variable to reuse.

Comment: @juharr: I'm not sure I follow. Where have I made that assumption? And the result of the `Any` call is a bool so how does assigning that to a variable help?

Comment: @Chris Then I guess I don't understand what you meant.  This will iterate the list only once, so it would only iterate it more than once if you call it more than once which is what I assumed you were talking about.  What makes it more efficient than `Count` is that it will stop iterating the list once it hits the 5th match.

Comment: @juharr: in comments on the question the OP said " I then need to check that list to make sure there are at least 5 of each item type in that list" which led me to believe that this was going to be called with variations multiple times and thus iterate the list multiple times. Sorry I was referring to comments from elsewhere on the page, I wasn't very clear (and I may have misread the OP's comment).

Comment: @chris - You understood what I was looking for, Juharr answered the question I asked - and what others will probably be looking for if they find this question. thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, youy've made me realise that I may not have been clear. I have absolutely no problem with the answer, was just adding supplemental information in response to your initial comment. Sorry if I wasn't clear on that, juharr!

Answer (score 2):

How about iterating though the list using a plain old for loop?:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; ++i)
{
    if (myList[i].PropertyX == desiredX && myList[i].Y != undesiredY)
       count++;

    if (count == 5)
       break;
}
```

This should be pretty much be as fast as it gets on a single thread. Since you can't make any assumption where in the list these items may be, the time complexity of the algorithm won't be better than be O(n) where n is the number of items in the list, i.e. in the worst case scenario you may have to iterate through the entire list. And there is no faster way of iterating through a list than using a for loop that I know of :)

Comment: I thought about this - If it comes down to needing something faster than `Skip` I'll come back and give this a try.

Comment: What is `c`?  Did you leave out `var c = myList[i];`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Skip` 4 elements and check if your collections has any other elements. In this way you willl not count the whole elements in the collection.

```
var result = myList.Where(c=>c.PropertyX == desiredX && c.Y != undesiredY);

if(result.Skip(4).Any())
{
    //has >= 5 elements.
}
```

Comment: That makes sure there is more than 5, not 5 or more.

Comment: @juharr Yep I don't see that he want >=, thanks for mention it.